# I have an error when I want to migrate to ovh host

Tags: mysql, ovh

When I want to migrate my project to the ovh database I get this error:

An exception occurred while executing the following

```
CREATE TABLE comment (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ad_id INT NOT NULL, author_id INT NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME   
  NOT NULL, rating INT NOT NULL, content LONGTEXT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_9474526C4F34D596 (ad_id), INDEX IDX_9474526CF675F31B (author_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB 


                                                                                                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'comment' already exists
```

Comment: And what about the error message don't you understand?

Comment: In my 'how' table I have: Engine InnoDB

Comment: try using ```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <tablename> ...```

Answer (score 0):

> Table 'comment' already exists

You should drop `comment` table before trying to execute the migration again.

```
DROP TABLE `comment`
```